# Multiple items inside CoordinatorLayout with infinite scrolling

Tags: android

I have `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbars"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:text="Rating AND Reviews for Burris 4-16x50mm Eliminator III Ballistic Laserscope Riflescope "
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"/>


    <com.app.views.recycleview.RecycleView
        android:id="@+id/reviews_star_filter_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/solid_white_border_gray_no_padding"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sort_by_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/solid_white_border_gray_no_padding"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <com.app.views.textviews.ReviewsAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/sort"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_gray_solid_gray_nop"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
            android:editable="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:text="test \nMost Helpful"
            android:textColor="@color/middle_gray"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2px"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.1"
                android:background="@color/divider_color_light"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Showing 1-40 of 1,465"
                android:textColor="@color/middle_gray"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/reset"
                android:textColor="@color/hyper_link"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2px"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/divider_color_light"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<com.app.opticsplanet.views.recycleview.VerticalRecycleView
   android:id="@+id/reviews_recycler_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/solid_white_border_gray_no_padding"
   android:overScrollMode="never"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

There is `InfinityListener` added to the `VerticalRecycleView`.
`VerticalRecycleView` has an endless scrolling. And it's works perfect.

But if there is < 10 items in the list, the infinite listener is disabled and in this case I would like to show `BottomView`.

But there is problem after reworking `VerticalRecycleView` to this container:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <com.app.opticsplanet.views.recycleview.VerticalRecycleView
                android:id="@+id/reviews_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:background="@drawable/solid_white_border_gray_no_padding"
                />

            <com.app.opticsplanet.views.BottomView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This Listener is not working:

```
mReviewsRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                {
                    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (loading) {
                        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                            loading = false;
                            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                            <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                        loading = true;
                        currentPage++;
                        loadNewPage(currentPage);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

How to fix it? Maybe there is other solution how to show `BottomView` if there is <10 items in the list ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using relative layout with parent bottom

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >

            <com.app.opticsplanet.views.recycleview.VerticalRecycleView
                android:id="@+id/reviews_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_view"
                android:background="@drawable/solid_white_border_gray_no_padding"
                />

            <com.app.opticsplanet.views.BottomView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```